# How to prevent multiple instances in Electron

Tags: electron

I do not know if this is possible but I might as well give it a chance and ask.
I'm doing an Electron app and I'd like to know if it is possible to have no more than a single instance at a time.

I have found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/olegam/10b87e3e54a859506a8d) but I'm not sure hot to use it. Can someone shed some light of share a better idea ?

```
var preventMultipleInstances = function(window) {
    var socket = (process.platform === 'win32') ? '\\\\.\\pipe\\myapp-sock' : path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'myapp.sock');
    net.connect({path: socket}, function () {
        var errorMessage = 'Another instance of ' + pjson.productName + ' is already running. Only one instance of the app can be open at a time.'
        dialog.showMessageBox(window, {'type': 'error', message: errorMessage, buttons: ['OK']}, function() {
            window.destroy()
        })
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        if (process.platform !== 'win32') {
            // try to unlink older socket if it exists, if it doesn't,
            // ignore ENOENT errors
            try {
                fs.unlinkSync(socket);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.code !== 'ENOENT') {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
        net.createServer(function (connection) {}).listen(socket);;
    });
}
```

Comment: Would you mind changing the accepted answer, because the Electron API has changed and now recommends `requestSingleInstanceLock` instead of `makeSingleInstance`

Comment: @Stefnotch sorted :)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

There is a new API now: [requestSingleInstanceLock](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#apprequestsingleinstancelock)

```js
const { app } = require('electron')
let myWindow = null
    
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()
    
if (!gotTheLock) {
  app.quit()
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
    if (myWindow) {
      if (myWindow.isMinimized()) myWindow.restore()
      myWindow.focus()
    }
  })
    
  // Create myWindow, load the rest of the app, etc...
  app.on('ready', () => {
  })
}
```

Comment: This is needed since electron 4.0

Comment: Keep in mind here that app.quit() doesn't terminate immediately, so if you have code afterwards it will still run.

Comment: What's the purpose of `app.quit()`? Why would I do it? Is it in case it failed to acquire the lock?

Comment: @felipecrs Pretty much. If the instance fails to acquire the lock, it means that it's a duplicate instance which, in this case, we want to close. Then, because the first instance was listening to `second-instance`, the window of that first instance is focused.

Comment: This code works, but doesn't make sense since basically what is happening we are running both the if and else logic. To my understanding the newly opened app will go into the 1st if and then close the newly opnened app. Our instance that is already running will go into the else statement and restore and focus it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 33):

Use the [`makeSingleInstance`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.36.10/docs/api/app.md#appmakesingleinstancecallback) function in the `app` module, there's even an example in the docs.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. I never seen that in their API. I was reading from here [http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/)

Comment: Release notes for Electron 4 say that `makeSingleInstance` [is deprecated](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/breaking-changes.md#planned-breaking-api-changes-40). Use `requestSingleInstanceLock`.

Answer (score 9):

In Case you need the code.

```
let mainWindow = null;
//to make singleton instance
const isSecondInstance = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
    if (mainWindow) {
        if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
        mainWindow.focus()
    }
})

if (isSecondInstance) {
    app.quit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only find one way to work electron 16, `makesingleinstance` is deprecated... use this:

```
  const additionalData = { myKey: 'myValue' };
  const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock(additionalData);

      if (!gotTheLock) {
        app.quit();
      } else {
        app.on(
        'second-instance',
        (event, commandLine, workingDirectory, additionalData) => {
          // Print out data received from the second instance.
          console.log(additionalData);
          // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
          if (mainWindow) {
            if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
            mainWindow.focus();
          }
        });
        app.whenReady().then(() => {
            createWindow();
        });
      }
```

Comment: And how is this different compared to the currently accepted answer?