# Prevent more than one BrowserWindow from opening electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am developing an app in electron and I want it confined to one window. On windows if you click on an apps icon a new window open, is there a way to disable this, so that the app is only confined to a single BrowserWindow ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633637/840992 Also: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-second-instance