# Multiple instances/windows on electron app

Tags: node.js, debugging, electron

i have a problematic problem... after i distributed my app, i have a bug on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. (i'm not sure about the reasons) it's just happening to open another window(with the same app) on top of the main one (smaller as size), even if i'm using "requestsingleInstanceLock".
AND it's weird also, because on windows neither on virtualbox (with the same platform) i can't open multiple instances/windows of the app.

As a better information about the app: i'm also using a device connected to main electron, which is listening for the numbers and "Enter" key from keyboard with (generalShortcuts) .. basically reading a rfid card and sending the data into renderer.

I saw all the similar questions and official documentation about this. and did, and tried them, but so far nothing is working and the bug is still persisting.

[How to prevent multiple instances in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916158/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-in-electron/52633637#52633637)
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelockadditionaldata

Device: Shuttle **with touch screen**
Platform: **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**
Npm: **8.1.0**
Electron: **13.6.1**
Node: **v16.13.0**

Did someone got this? Can it be an ubuntu bug (which one)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Found the issue! On my screen i had a "button" made as link (<a>) not as <button> AND  my rfid reader, was sending beside the numbers of rfid, character ENTER (which) was good(i needed it), and another character(i'm not sure but i'm assuming it was SHIFT) and this combo(SHIFT + ENTER) + the href="#" from the button we're opening a new tab...